# Php pagination with SQL not working

Tags: php, sql

I have done this pagination using PHP and SQL. Id 11 and 12 is missing in the page 2 module. I can't find out where my mistake is.
Here my source code:

```
<?php
$per_page = 5;
$rec_count = $row['id'];
$total_pages = ceil($rec_count / $per_page);         

if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $show_page = $_GET['page']; //current page
    if ($show_page > 0 && $show_page <= $total_pages) {
        $start = ($show_page - 1) * $per_page;
        $end = $start + $per_page;
    } else {
        $start = 0;
        $end = $per_page;
    }
} else {
    $start = 0;
    $end = $per_page;
}

$page = intval($_GET['page']);
$tpages=$total_pages;
if ($page <= 0)
    $page = 1;

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(Id) AS id FROM [Register].[dbo].[RegisData] WHERE DeleteStatus = 1";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql); 
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
$rec_count = $row['id'];
$total_pages = ceil($rec_count / $per_page);

$sql1 = "SELECT [Id],[FirstName],[LastName],[ProfilePic],[Gender]
         ,[Email],[MobileNo],[Company],[Designation],[Country],[State],[Address],[City]
         ,[Pincode],[Hobbies],[DietaryHabits],[DeleteStatus] 
        FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RegId) as row 
        FROM [Register].[dbo].[RegisData]) 
        a WHERE row between $start and $end 
        AND DeleteStatus = 1 
        ORDER BY RegId";

$result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql1);
$z = 1;
for ($x=1; $x<=$total_pages; $x++) {
    echo $x;
}  
?>
```

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSAuk.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwRFw.jpg
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMbSC.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way you did the pagination combined with `DeleteStatus = 1` will always create broken and incomplete pages (if you take all the rows between 1 and 5 and row number 4 is `DeleteStatus = 0` you will only get 4 rows)

you should use SQL's `LIMIT` functionality that allows you to select the result row number to start and how many rows to show **after the `WHERE` clause**
so try

```
$page = intval($_GET['page']);
if($page == 0) $page = 1;
$per_page = 5;
$offset = ($page -1) * $per_page;

$sql1 = "SELECT [Id],[FirstName],[LastName],[ProfilePic],[Gender]
     ,[Email],[MobileNo],[Company],[Designation],[Country],[State],[Address],[City]
     ,[Pincode],[Hobbies],[DietaryHabits],[DeleteStatus] 
    FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RegId) as row 
    FROM [Register].[dbo].[RegisData]) 
    a WHERE DeleteStatus = 1 
    ORDER BY RegId
    LIMIT {$per_page} OFFSET {$offset}";
```

for more on `LIMIT` in SQL look at this short explanation: https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/select_limit.php it's really what you're looking for

---EDIT----

since you don't want to use my suggested solution (for unknown reasons) you can try to make this change to your code:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT [Id],[FirstName],[LastName],[ProfilePic],[Gender]
     ,[Email],[MobileNo],[Company],[Designation],[Country],[State],[Address],[City]
     ,[Pincode],[Hobbies],[DietaryHabits],[DeleteStatus] 
    FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RegId) as row 
    FROM [Register].[dbo].[RegisData] WHERE DeleteStatus = 1) 
    a WHERE row between $start and $end 
    AND DeleteStatus = 1 
    ORDER BY RegId";
```

what I did is add the `WHERE DeleteStatus = 1` condition to the internal query that numbers the lines, this way your filter should work as expected - although you should use `LIMIT`

To prevent duplicates (5 appearing both for page 1 and page 2) you should change this if:

```
 if ($show_page > 0 && $show_page <= $total_pages) {
    $start = ($show_page - 1) * $per_page;
    $end = $start + $per_page;
}
```

to this:

```
 if ($show_page > 1 && $show_page <= $total_pages) {
    $start = ($show_page - 1) * $per_page + 1;
    $end = $start + $per_page;
}
```

again, if you would have used `LIMIT` this would not be an issue

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply sir ;-). I am using SQL as back end not MYSQL sir.

Comment: Sir, I am not using delete query so instead of this i use update as "DeleteStatus=0" so i used "DeleteStatus=1"

Comment: Hello friend! first thing, we should retag your question :D I've updated my answer to work with SQL - `LIMIT` appears in all the DB's just slightly different. and I understand what you did with `DeleteStatus` and it's fine but that is where your problem is with this query

Comment: Sir kindly look the URL link with include the Table and output
[1]: i.stack.imgur.com/lSAuk.jpg 
[2]: i.stack.imgur.com/DwRFw.jpg 
[3]: i.stack.imgur.com/VMbSC.jpg

Comment: I did, what's the issue?

Comment: @S.Shyam - I don't seem to understand your problem with `LIMIT` but I've added to my answer a different solution that you might prefer

Comment: Sir, kindly look the link 
http://i.stack.imgur.com/lSAuk.jpg
http://i.stack.imgur.com/DwRFw.jpg
http://i.stack.imgur.com/VMbSC.jpg
Pagination is not working properly sir. I don't know what mistake i did.

Comment: Friend, I'm pretty sure I do know what mistake you did - you use `ROW_NUMBER()` to set the number of items to show - but you do not apply same `WHERE` clause on that list - try changing `$sql1` to the second code in my answer and I believe it will work as expected

Comment: Thanks sir after change the code it is working fine but in first page "5" th record is coming to the second page also.

Comment: yes, that's another logic flow in your code, I've added a solution to that as well in my answer (think what `$start` and `$end` are for page 2 - `5` and `10` and you want it to be `6` and `11`)

Comment: Sir thank you very much for quick response and logic. My pagination is working perfect. How I can give you rating sir? :-)

Comment: happy to hear! I'm afraid you still cannot +1 me - since you do not have enough reputation - but you can mark my answer as accepted :-)

Comment: Respected sir, i have already given you "answer is useful" but showing pop up like "this answer can be accepted after 15 reputation" did you got that mark sir? :-)

Comment: Ummm I've actually never posted a question, but there is an explanation right here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235 is says ther is a 15 minute delay, nothing about reputation. you should be able to see a gray V under the 0 and arrows to the left of my answer

Comment: Sir, if I click the "This answer is useful" tap the triangle button it is showing some message . Pls click this like sir "https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynUqc.jpg" . But i clicked the tick "answer is accepted" :-) . Keep in touch sir :-)